# Problems using MSI to authenticate to Azure BlobStorage

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs, service-principal

I am trying to connect my C# console app (.net core 2.1) to blob storage.  I initialise the Blob Storage client in a couple of different ways.  They are:

1. **Connection String** - useful during development
2. **Service Principle** - possibility for production deployment
3. **MSI Authentication** - more secure, keys are automatically cycled for us

In my code, if the connection string is not explicitly set, I generate it using a service principle or MSI depending on app settings defined (sample initialisation code below).  No matter which of the three ways I use, I will ultimately initialise the client using a connection string (either its explicitly set in case of 1. or generated with my code in case of 2. and  3.).

The code below works 100% fine for 1 (connection string) and 2 (service principle) BUT I am getting an error when attempting to achieve 3 (MSI).

When running locally I get this error:

> The access token is from the wrong issuer
>   'https://sts.windows.net/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/'. It
>   must match the tenant
>   'https://sts.windows.net/{my-subscription-id}/'
>   associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL)
>   'https://login.windows.net/{my-subscription-id}' to
>   get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another
>   tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new
>   tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just
>   transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try
>   back later.

With this, I have no idea where 'f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a' comes from, it could be the global Microsoft instance.  I tried to mitigate this by running my code in a webjob within Azure which has MSI enabled to see if that works, I get:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An exception
>   occurred during service connection, see inner exception for more
>   detail) ---> System.Exception: An exception occurred during service
>   connection, see inner exception for more detail --->
>   Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: The client '{my-subscription-id}'
>   with object id '{my-subscription-id}' does not have authorization to
>   perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/read' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/{my-subscription-id}'.

(*note* I have the MSI account set as 'owner' and 'Storage Account Key Operator' of blob storage)

I initialise the CloudStorageAccount client in the following way:

```
public void InitializeClient()
{
    // Always using the connection string, no matter how it's generated.
    if (ConnectionString.IsNullOrEmpty()) // if not already set, then build.
        ConnectionString = BuildStorageConnection().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(ConnectionString, out var storageAccount);

    if (storageAccount == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot find storage account");

    // CloudBlobClient that represents the Blob storage endpoint.
    _cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
}
```

And build a connection string as follows:

```
internal async Task<string> BuildStorageConnection()
{
    try
    {
        string token = null;

        if (Config.UseMsi)
        {
            // Managed Service Identity (MSI) authentication.
            var provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            token = provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not authenticate using Managed Service Identity");

            _expiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        }
        else
        {
            // Service Principle authentication
            // Grab an authentication token from Azure.
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + Config.TenantId);

            var credential = new ClientCredential(Config.AppId, Config.AppSecret);
            var tokenResult = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", credential).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            if (tokenResult == null || tokenResult.AccessToken == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not authenticate using Service Principle");

            _expiryTime = tokenResult.ExpiresOn;
            token = tokenResult.AccessToken;
        }

        // Set credentials and grab the authenticated REST client.
        var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(token);

        var client = RestClient.Configure()
            .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
            .WithCredentials(new AzureCredentials(tokenCredentials, tokenCredentials, string.Empty, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud))
            .WithRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(new HttpStatusCodeErrorDetectionStrategy(), new FixedIntervalRetryStrategy(3, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))))
            .Build();

        // Authenticate against the management layer.
        var azureManagement = Azure.Authenticate(client, string.Empty).WithSubscription(Config.SubscriptionId);

        // Get the storage namespace for the passed in instance name.
        var storageNamespace = azureManagement.StorageAccounts.List().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == Config.StorageInstanceName);

        // If we cant find that name, throw an exception.
        if (storageNamespace == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not find the storage instance {Config.StorageInstanceName} in the subscription with ID {Config.SubscriptionId}");
        }

        // Storage accounts use access keys - this will be used to build a connection string.
        var accessKeys = await storageNamespace.GetKeysAsync();

        // If the access keys are not found (not configured for some reason), throw an exception.
        if (accessKeys == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not find access keys for the storage instance {Config.StorageInstanceName}");
        }

        // We just default to the first key.
        var key = accessKeys[0].Value;

        // Build and return the connection string.
        return $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={Config.StorageInstanceName};AccountKey={key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger?.LogError(e, "An exception occured during connection to blob storage");
        throw new Exception("An exception occurred during service connection, see inner exception for more detail", e);
    }
}
```

The main difference in how I'm getting the access token is that using service principle I have an authentication context and using MSI I do not.  Is this effecting the scope of authentication?  Any help and advice with this much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realised how to resolve the issue above - changing the GetTokenAsync to have a second parameter of TenantId gives context to the authentication call.

Here's the code you will need:

```
token = await provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", Config.TenantId);
```